# load 2 differents json angular router

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript, angular-httpclient

I have a json that I call via a service and that I call in my component.ts and I make a loop on it in my html all works well, but I would like that when I click on an element I have a parameter that I retrieve via the route method a different json that is displayed.

**my question is: how to load another json file when clicking on an item?**

the both json path is :

'./assets/json/one/first.json'

'./assets/json/two/second.json'

**first json** // currently I load this json

```
{
      "flags": [
       {
        "name": "one",
        "libelle": "test"
       }
      ],
    }
```

**second json**

```
{
  "flags": [
   {
    "name": "two",
    "libelle": "test 2"
   }
  ],
}
```

**service**

```
private url1 = './assets/json/one/first.json'

constructor(private http: HttpCient) {}

get(): Observable<Itoto[]> {
return this.http.get<Itoto[]>(this.url1);
}
```

**ts.file**

```
public exampleArray: any = [] 


 getALL() {
  this.totoService.getAll().susbcribe(result => {
   this.exampleArray= result
     });
    }

route(name:string) {
 this.router.navigate(['/homepage', (name)]);
 console.log('name);
}
```

**routing.module**

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
 {
   path: 'homepage/:name',
   component: FooComponent
 }
]
```

**html**

```
 <div *ngFor=" let toto of exampleArray.flags">
     {{toto.libelle}}
   <span (click)="route(toto.name)">click</span>
 </div>
```

Comment: simply pass the API url from the component like if you want to get the response from the `first json`  then pass the first json url if you want the response from the `second json` then pass the url of send json

Comment: I know this solution but there is a way to do it with the router and this is the way I want to do it.

Comment: need help please anyone know ?